# Get OSX version with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How would I be able to get the OSX version in objective-c?  I would like to avoid using shell commands.  E.g "10.5" or "10.4"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X: Replacement for Gestalt() for testing OS version at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072804/mac-os-x-replacement-for-gestalt-for-testing-os-version-at-runtime)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
NSProcessInfo *pInfo = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];
NSString *version = [pInfo operatingSystemVersionString];
```

Sorry for the formatting, I'm using my iPad to answer this.

Comment: That's fine if you want to display the version to the user, but not fine if you want to do processing based on the OS version.

Comment: This works, but there is a lot of "garbage" text that is added with it (Build information etc).

Comment: @JeremyP there is method `operatingSystemVersion` gives you a struct with three integers, major, minor and patch version which might be easier to process

Answer (score 10):

As of 10.10 you can use `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion` to get a NSOperatingSystemVersion struct.

```
typedef struct {
    NSInteger majorVersion;
    NSInteger minorVersion;
    NSInteger patchVersion;
} NSOperatingSystemVersion;
```

There's also a helpful `isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:` method.

```
NSOperatingSystemVersion minimumSupportedOSVersion = { .majorVersion = 10, .minorVersion = 12, .patchVersion = 0 };
BOOL isSupported = [NSProcessInfo.processInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:minimumSupportedOSVersion];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can parse it in this way to get the format you want:

```
NSProcessInfo *pinfo = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];

NSArray *myarr = [[pinfo operatingSystemVersionString] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *version = [@"Mac OS X " stringByAppendingString:[myarr objectAtIndex:1]];
```

This f.e. will give you `Mac OS X 10.6.8`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `Gestalt` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Gestalt_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/Gestalt) to access [the components of the OS version](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Gestalt_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000036-CH4g-SystemVersionSelector).

Old-time users of `Gestalt` may be amazed to find that it is still available in 64-bit.

Comment: It's now deprecated in OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: ..with no decent replacement that would be as comprehensive as Gestalt is/was :-(

Answer (score 1):

See this response using `NSAppKitVersionNumber` in case you're using AppKit in your app as well (and want to run on 10.8+ as Gestalt is now deprecated):

[How to know what Mac OS the app is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055146/how-to-know-what-mac-os-the-app-is-running-on/11056915#11056915)

Answer (score -1):

add this code after `#import`

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
```

after adding above code please add below code where you want to see your os-version

```
NSString *systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        NSLog(@"System version :%@",systemVersion);
```

you can easily get OS-version by above code

Thank you