# How to know what Mac OS the app is running on?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I've seen in some projects something like:

```
#if .....
    code...
#endif
```

but i can't find it now...
Let's say, for example, if the app is running on 10.8 the app does 1 thing, if not the app does other thing.
Whats to code to check if it's running on 10.8?

Thanks.

Comment: I did a quick check, and this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157759/how-can-i-determine-the-running-mac-os-x-version-programmatically

Comment: A CPP #define/#if is *not* your friend here. That is a *compilation* switch (e.g. what platform/feature is being *targeted*).

Comment: #if .... #endif is a preprocessor that runs at compile time, I use this to determine between dev, qa(test) and release.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X: Replacement for Gestalt() for testing OS version at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072804/mac-os-x-replacement-for-gestalt-for-testing-os-version-at-runtime)

Comment: @JakePetroules if you look closely, my question was asked before that one, so it means that question is the duplicate.

Comment: @PedroVieira Yes but that question has the most up to date and correct answer. Stack Overflow is a public wiki, and the preference goes towards the best and most correct answers, not necessarily which one was first.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're probably asking the wrong question. Except in very rare cases, you should not care what system version the user is running. Instead, you should be checking if the specific thing you're interested in is available.

For instance, if Apple introduces a MagicHologram class in Mac OS X 10.9 that you want to use, you don't check if the user is running Mac OS X 10.9. Instead, you check if the MagicHologram class is available. If it is, you can use it. If not, it's not available. It doesn't even matter why. Maybe they're running 10.8. But maybe it's five years later, and Apple's decided to drop the MagicHologram class entirely.

(Also, keep in mind that you'd need to weak link to HologramKit, the library that provides the MagicHologram class.)

Likewise, if they introduce a new method to NSString, instead of checking the OS version you'd check if NSString knows about the new method.

That said, NSApplication.h includes an external constant called `NSAppKitVersionNumber`. You can compare this to constants like `NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7` which (it should be noted) are numbers like 1138, not 10.7. There's only a few places this is appropriate, mostly where classes were private and undocumented but got major changes before being documented and becoming a part of the public parts of the SDK. Also, it might be helpful if you want to avoid a specific bug that's been fixed since.

To recap:

1. Detect individual classes and methods, which should cover 99.44% of your cases.
2. Use `NSAppKitVersionNumber` and `NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7` to cover those cases where class or method detection would lie to you.
3. Those first two points cover all *normal* cases. You should go no further. But if you must have behaviour based on humane version, look at abarnert's answer below. It's the sanest way to get them.
4. Don't use `operatingSystemVersionString`, which is specifically listed as not safe for parsing.

References/more information:

- [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html) "Read this document if you want your application to target a specific version or multiple versions of iOS or Mac OS X."

  - [Using SDK-Based Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6) Describes how to use weakly linked classes, methods, and functions to support running on multiple versions of an operating system.

Answer (score 13):

A quick way to do it is:

```
if ( NSAppKitVersionNumber >= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7 ) {

    // Do stuff for Lion or later
}
```

More [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html).

You can see all the constants available in NSApplication.h, which you can get to by using Open Quickly... (Cmd-Shift O) in Xcode.

The header files provide for some surprisingly interesting reading material, if you are so inclined.

Comment: I think the shortcut is Cmd-Shift-D by default

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't cover every revision of Mac OS X, and there is no way to future-proof if (e.g. if you're trying to report the OS version for diagnostic purposes.)

Answer (score 4):

As others have said above (and I'd pick Steven Fisher's answer), you usually do not actually want to get the version number.

And if you only need to do comparisons against a major OS X version up to the version of the current SDK you're using, NSAppKitVersionNumber (as in Monolo's answer) is the right way to do it.

If you actually do need to get the version number for some reason (e.g., for recording analytics about your users, so you can decide when to stop supporting 10.6.0-10.6.5), here's how to do it:

```
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
SInt32 majorVersion, minorVersion, bugFixVersion;
Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMajor, &majorVersion);
Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &minorVersion);
Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionBugFix, &bugFixVersion);
```

For 10.7.3, this gives majorVersion = 10, minorVersion = 7, bugFixVersion = 3.

The 10.7 documentation removed the paragraph that directly suggested Gestalt as the way to get OS version, but it's still not deprecated or legacy, and there's no other suggestions. In fact, every other way to get this information (parsing -[NSProcessInfo operatingSystemVersionString], calling sysctlbyname on "kern.osrelease" and converting Darwin kernel version to OS X version, etc.) is explicitly counter-indicated somewhere. So, this is the way to do it, if you really want to.

Just keep in mind that, as the release notes for System 6.0.4 said back in 1989, this new API may not be permanent and could be removed in a future version of the OS.

Comment: Make sure if you're doing this that you write the comparisons correctly. Someone at my company (not me (wink)) once wrote a routine that detected 10.4.0 as older than 10.3.1, because 0 was lower than 1. :)

Comment: @StevenFisher: I've never done that; I just did a greater-equal when I meant greater. :) But the more common problem is converting the whole thing to a string and then comparing strings, which works perfectly until 10.4.10 comes out (because "10.4.10" is less than "10.4.9"). You could use NSNumericSearch/kCFCompareNumerically to avoid this—but even easier, just compare the numbers before stringifying.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current release from the `uname -r` command (that's actually the kernel release, though it's easy to map onto Mac OS X versions), from the `sw_vers` command which gives you the release name, version and build identifier, or from the `Gestalt()` function (on current versions of Mac OS X, anyway). The safest way is probably to read the output of `sw_vers` which is in a stable format that's easy to parse.

Notice that you probably don't want to know what version of the OS you're on, though. What you probably want to do is to test whether a particular feature is available. You can do this by weak-linking frameworks, by weak class references, or by inspecting whether a class responds to selectors appropriate to the feature you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

As Steven Fisher said, you should not check for the system version but for the availability of the class or method you want to use.

The check if a specific class is available use

```
if ([NSHologram class]) {
   // Create an instance of the class and use it.
} else {
   // The Hologram class is not available.
}
```

To check if a specific method is available use

```
NSString* hologramText = @"Hologram";
if ([hologramText respondsToSelector:@selector(convertHologram)]) {
    [hologramText convertHologram];
}
```

Yet for the method checking, the method must be available on the system where you build your app, or else you will get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for how I do it. I love it this way, mainly because I don't have to A) Rely on an NSTask or B) Rely on any File I/O that many processes have access to.

```
static NSString* const kVarSysInfoVersionFormat  = @"%@.%@.%@ (%@)";
static NSString* const kVarSysInfoKeyOSVersion = @"kern.osrelease";
static NSString* const kVarSysInfoKeyOSBuild   = @"kern.osversion";

- (NSString *) _strControlEntry:(NSString *)ctlKey {

    size_t size = 0;
    if ( sysctlbyname([ctlKey UTF8String], NULL, &size, NULL, 0) == -1 ) return nil;

    char *machine = calloc( 1, size );

    sysctlbyname([ctlKey UTF8String], machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *ctlValue = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

    free(machine); return ctlValue;
}

- (NSString *) getOSVersionInfo {

    NSString *darwinVer = [self _strControlEntry:kVarSysInfoKeyOSVersion];
    NSString *buildNo = [self _strControlEntry:kVarSysInfoKeyOSBuild];
    if ( !darwinVer || !buildNo ) return nil;

    NSString *majorVer = @"10", *minorVer = @"x", *bugFix = @"x";
    NSArray *darwinChunks = [darwinVer componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];

    if ( [darwinChunks count] > 0 ) {

        NSInteger firstChunk = [(NSString *)[darwinChunks objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
        minorVer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (firstChunk - 4)];
        bugFix = [darwinChunks objectAtIndex:1];

    } return [NSString stringWithFormat:kVarSysInfoVersionFormat, majorVer, minorVer, bugFix, buildNo];
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score -4):

You can get OS version like this:

```
NSString *version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString];

NSLog(version);
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

---

And I see You want to get just version. It can be done like this:

```
NSString *version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(8, 4);
NSString *justVersion = [version substringWithRange: range];

NSLog(@"%@", justVersion);
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

And for checking:

```
if ([justVersion isEqualToString:@"10.7"]) {
    code...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In the documentation: "this string is _not_ appropriate for parsing."

Comment: Also note that the format of that string varies based on the user's locale.

Comment: Agreed, very very wrong. In fact the doco indicates that using [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString]; is for display purposes only and should not be parsed.